# How to get unique data from list of object in "dart"

Tags: database, flutter, dart, collections

When I save user location on local Database, I am successful in saving, however, when I retrieve the data, there are multiple data for each day. I want to eliminate redundancy by adding unique data in List and I am unable to do it.. please refer the cose snippet below, any leads is appreciated!

```
if (data != null) {
  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!day.contains*(data[i].date)) {*
      day.add*(data[i]);
    }
  }
  daycount = data.length;
  print('count ${daycount}')*;
}
```

data model used

```
class Note {
  int _id;
  String _longitude;
  String _latitude;
  String _date;
```

Comment: What's with all the stars in your code?

Comment: And what is the structure of the data you are working with? What are you attempting to accomplish? What is this code doing differently than what you want it to do? Asking your question as a long run-on sentence makes what you are trying to achieve really unclear.

Comment: @Abion47 i have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate duplicate values, you'll need a way to determine if 2 `Note` objects are "equal". You might say 2 `Note`s are equal if the `id` is the same. Or maybe the `id` and `longitude` *and* `latitude` have to *all* be the same. Maybe the `date`. It's up to you.

Basically you should override the the `==` operator, and the `hashcode` method. The `==` operator should return true if the `hashcode` method produces the same hashcode.

Once you've implemented this, you can add your `Note` objects to a `Set` instead of a `List`. A `Set` doesn't allow for duplicate values, and will use the == / hashcode features of the object to determine equality.

Answer (score 0):

```
              if (data != null) {
                List day = [];
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  day.add(data[i].date);
              }
                var dictinctsday =day.toSet().toList();
                print('filtered $dictinctsday');

              }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks brother for your suggestion,this is important for me